# What is efficient way to updates records of mysql database table from a xml file which contains updated information?

Tags: c#, xml, database, insert-update

I am using MySQL as a database which contains large amount of data in various tables.I want to update records of different tables with different fields in efficient way.I have xml file which contains records with updated information for all the tables which needs to be updated.Please suggest efficient way to perform such operation using c#.NET

Answer (score 0):

First read the xml file and put the data of tables in datatable of dataset.
write the ado.net code to update the data of database table from datatable in dataset.